# trying to make a star using sine and cosine

Tags: java, swing, trigonometry, java-2d, japplet

so I'm trying to make a star for a program where I am going to draw a flag. I'm pretty much limited to the Java Applet class. since the process should be the same for every star with a different center, I figured I would pass the center to a method with X and Y values, and then draw it based off the angle from the center using Polygon. The problem is the shapes that are coming out are not in any way stars.

```
public void paint( Graphics g)
{
    super.paint( g );
    Polygon star= new Polygon();
    int radius=20;
    int roundX=(int)Math.round(radius*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(54)));
    int roundY=(int)Math.round(radius*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(54)));
    int originX=100,originY=100;
    //int radius=20;
    int topY=originY+radius;
    int bottomLeftX=originX+roundX;
    int bottomY=originY-roundY;
    int middleY=originY+(int)Math.round(radius*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(18)));;
    int midRightX=originX+(int)Math.round(radius*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(18)));;
    int midLeftX=originX-(int)Math.round(radius*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(18)));
    int bottomRightX=originX+roundX;
    int bottomRightY=middleY-roundY;
    star.addPoint(originX, originY);
    star.addPoint(originX, topY);
    star.addPoint(bottomLeftX, bottomY);
    star.addPoint(midRightX, middleY);
    //star.addPoint(midLeftX, middleY);
    //star.addPoint(bottomRightX, bottomY);
    //star.addPoint(originX, topY);
    g.drawPolygon(star);
}
```

so the bottom left point should be 234 degrees from the center or 54 degrees from the x axis. when I code this either of these in and change the operation(+ or minus) it seems to shoot in the opposite direction than what I intended. The middle points should be 18 degrees above the center, though from the way it looks they look almost in line with the x axis. I've been disabling the points one by one to see if I can tweak it to get closer to a star, but at this I've realized that's the equivalent of sculpting while blindfolded and drunk.

if you could help me figure out what's wrong, I would greatly appreciated it.

Comment: A little sketch of the sort of image/s you are expecting/wanting could help, would you mind adding some?

Comment: *"I'm pretty much limited to the Java Applet class."* 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See also [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want a five-pointed star.

```
private double sin(int degree) {
    return Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degree));
}

private double cos(int degree) {
    return Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degree));
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Polygon star = new Polygon();

    int radius = 20;
    int originX = 100;
    int originY = 100;
    int innerRadius = (int) Math.round(radius * sin(18) / sin(126));

    Point[] points = new Point[11];
    // top center 
    points[0] = new Point();
    points[0].x = 0;
    points[0].y = -radius;
    // inner top left
    points[1] = new Point();
    points[1].x = -(int) Math.round(innerRadius * cos(54));
    points[1].y = -(int) Math.round(innerRadius * sin(54));
    // top left 
    points[2] = new Point();
    points[2].x = -(int) Math.round(radius * cos(18));
    points[2].y = -(int) Math.round(radius * sin(18));
    // inner bottom left
    points[3] = new Point();
    points[3].x = -(int) Math.round(innerRadius * cos(18));
    points[3].y = (int) Math.round(innerRadius * sin(18));
    // bottom left
    points[4] = new Point();
    points[4].x = -(int) Math.round(radius * cos(54));
    points[4].y = (int) Math.round(radius * sin(54));
    // inner bottom center
    points[5] = new Point();
    points[5].x = 0;
    points[5].y = innerRadius;
    // bottom right
    points[6] = new Point();
    points[6].x = (int) Math.round(radius * cos(54));
    points[6].y = (int) Math.round(radius * sin(54));
    // inner bottom right
    points[7] = new Point();
    points[7].x = (int) Math.round(innerRadius * cos(18));
    points[7].y = (int) Math.round(innerRadius * sin(18));
    // top right
    points[8] = new Point();
    points[8].x = (int) Math.round(radius * cos(18));
    points[8].y = -(int) Math.round(radius * sin(18));
    // inner top right
    points[9] = new Point();
    points[9].x = (int) Math.round(innerRadius * cos(54));
    points[9].y = -(int) Math.round(innerRadius * sin(54));
    // top center
    points[10] = new Point();
    points[10].x = 0;
    points[10].y = -radius;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        star.addPoint(originX + points[i].x, originY + points[i].y);
    }
    g.drawPolygon(star);

}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that the Point class existed. now I'm just going to work on encapsulating this in method because I have to call it 50 times.

Comment: you've already helped plenty, but when I try to encapsulate it I'm having trouble calling it from within a method, I can't pass Graphics g to the method, and I can't return the star object in order to get g to draw it? you don't have to write it in code, but how might I go about putting this inside a method i can call? I mainly just need a point in the right direction, a link to the appropriate documentation would do.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You can change the method paint() in my code easily to return the created Polygon-star-object. Just remove everything with the variable g and change the return-type to Polygon and return the created star-object at the end. And change the name. I can't help with documentation, but I think you could google for it.